# Capturing Multiple Elements in List Using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `output` that I am trying to capture a list of items from using regex matching.  The string is as follows ...

```
ltm virtual test_vs {
    profiles {
        foo_bar {
            context all
        }
        baz {
            context one
        }
        qux {
            context all
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is do is come up with a regex that will match on the whole string and capture `foo_bar`, `baz`, and `qux` out of it, without knowing the values of these captures beforehand.  Also, I want it to be flexible in that there can be any number of items to capture; they will just always be in between `profiles` brackets and each have open and closed brackets themselves with `context ANYWORD` in between their own brackets.  What I have so far is ...

```
List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
regex = "ltm\\svirtual\\stest_vs\\s\\{\\s*\\n\\s*profiles\\s\\{"+TODO;
pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
matcher = pattern.matcher(output);
while(matcher.find()) {
    itemList.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Just need some help filling in the rest of the `regex`.  Suggestions?

Comment: You'll want to use capture groups to be able to extract parts of the matched text.  If you really have line breaks as shown you'll probably need the MULTILINE and DOTALL options to your pattern.

Comment: Can there be nested brackets also like `qux { { anything } }` ?

Comment: try the simpleJSON library

Comment: @anubhava No there can't be any nested brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex based on `\G` that asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match:

```
String regex = "(?:\\bprofiles\\s*\\{|(?<!^)\\G)[^{]+?(\\b\\w+\\b)\\s*\\{[^}]*}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output);

List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
while(matcher.find()) {
    itemList.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dQ6pE0/1)

Comment: Hmmm, I copied and pasted your regex exactly and it's throwing the following exception:  `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 15
(?:\bprofiles\s*{|(?<!^)\G)[^{]+?(\b\w+\b)\s*{[^}]*}`

Comment: Are you able to compile that regex in Java? The demo clearly works though.

Comment: Check updated answer. Java needs `{` to be escaped as well.

Answer (score 0):

`([^\\s]+)\\s+\\{\\n\\s*context\\s` if the input is really this simple. Lots of things can go wrong however, e.g. if one of the profiles is called "context".

Otherwise, it could be better to parse it (as JSON or writing your own parser) rather than use regex.

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I'm trying to debug it in a regex tester.